# Did I install this "weatherproof outdoor extension ring" correctly?

Tags: electrical, exterior

I have patio wall lights and I'd like to add additional lighting in the garden on the same switch. So I have installed an outdoor outlet with an extension ring with holes on the bottom where I can run the uf-b or rigid conduit or what have you, to the garden lights.

After this initial installation, I have 4 leftover bolts from the kit, and some holes where they seem to fit. I couldn't find videos online aside from promotional videos from Gardner or whatever, so there wasn't much instruction to go on here.

#### 1. Cut siding and installed the outlet box

The other side of this has conduit running to the existing switch indoors.

[image: Outlet box]

#### 2. Install extension ring over outlet box

The extension ring included this gasket and screws, so I used them.

[image: Gasket]

[image: Extension ring]

#### 3. Outlet cover over extension ring.

Here is where I'm confused. I assume I'll be installing the outlet here, where these screws are. The plastic here is flexing a lot and I don't think the gasket between the outlet cover and the extension ring is getting a good seal. Doesn't smell right.

[image: Flexing]

Comment: I think the outlet is supposed to go between the metal box and the gray water resistant outlet cover.  Then you screw the gray cover through the mounting ears of the outlet and into the metal box.

Comment: That makes sense. So I will: 1. Remove the outlet cover. 2. Install the outlet directly to the extension ring. 3. Mount the outlet cover to the ears of the outlet. There are also four bolt-holes in the corners of the outlet cover, pictured in my last photo. I think I need bolts for those.

Comment: You should have enough room to 1) wire the outlet with the required 6"-8" lead length; 2) pull the outlet out away from the metal box; 3) wiggle the gray cover over the outlet.  Then fasten as described above.

Comment: You're right, it was pretty easy to remove that panel

Comment: Other than that, was it okay how I installed the outlet box _under_ the siding, and the extension ring to the outlet box _over_ the siding? There seems to be a gap. Only the outlet box is grounded as far as I can tell. How is this extension ring supposed to be grounded? There's no threads for a grounding screw or anything

Comment: What's up with that blue wire - it looks like there's some sort of twist in the insulation and that's very odd.

Comment: It's a switched-hot from the motion sensor I marked with blue tape. Same with the yellow one, that's the switched-hot going to the lights.

Comment: @Frambot If the extension ring is metal (can't really tell from the photos), it is grounded through the screws mounting it to the box. Incidentally, it would also be grounded through the screws mounting a receptacle in (the receptacle also being grounded via the ground screw).

Comment: Re: "I installed the outlet box under the siding, and the extension ring to the outlet box over the siding" I thought the weatherproof extension gasket should go directly on a weatherproof electrical box open face - it's not extending the siding, it's extending the box. The box plus extension ring etc should all be watertight. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that "I have installed an outdoor outlet" means that you've installed this metal junction box in your wall, and that you're not talking about an actual receptacle that you could plug things into.

You are planning on running this wiring *out* of this box. Therefore, what you have in the 3rd picture (posted below for convenience) seems to be as far as you need to go with the assembly/installation of this extension ring.

[image: extension box mounted to wall]
<sup>Click to embiggen or just scroll up.</sup>

From here, knock out the appropriate plug(s), attach your conduit to the extension, wire up the connections to the wires in the conduit, and put the cover plate on this box. You're done.

Comment: I'm a little confused, why would I have exposed wiring? I just pulled the bundle aside for a better picture.

Comment: To the other question, yes I intend to install an outlet here. The wire bundle contains: 12ga hot, neutral, ground; 14ga hot (to motion sensor), switched-hot (from motion sensor), switched-hot (to lights), neutral

Comment: I don't see why you can't install a receptacle there, provided you don't exceed the fill requirements for the box (which have been increased by the extension ring anyway.  There is nothing that says a box can't be both a junction box and an outlet.  You have the sandwich made already: from inside to out you have Box>Siding>Extension Ring (exterior conduit would exit one of the provided holes)>Receptacle>In-Use Cover.

Comment: Perfect, glad to have confirmation on this. Thanks.

Comment: @Frambot I've updated the answer with an image that I hope explains the issue as I see it. If I'm totally off base, maybe update your original question with the receptacle in place and the wiring headed out one of those conduit exits, at least as a temporary, held in place so we can see what you're planning on doing.

Comment: You can see in the second picture that there are mounting tabs on the extension ring for a receptacle. They were removed in the third picture to access the screws behind it.

Comment: @Frambot I was so focused on the 3rd picture that I totally missed the 2nd one. In this case, my concerns are totally addressed and this isn't going to be an issue at all.